# How to check for null on onWillPop values?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to do a null check:

```js
onWillPop: () async {
        return !await listOfKeys[tabController!.index].currentState!.maybePop();
      },
```

Instead of "!" should I use "??". But I can't write it down. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use the null safety operator ´??´ you should provide a fallback value:

```
    onWillPop: () async {
      return tabController != null
      ? !(await listOfKeys[tabController?.index].currentState?.maybePop() ?? false)
      : false;
    },
```

Comment: still got an error in [tabController?.index]:  The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

Comment: you should check for TabController nullSafety before,

´return tabController != null
? !(await listOfKeys[tabController!.index].currentState?.maybePop() ?? false)
: false;´